# Google Sheets - Is there a way to toggle permissions between viewer and editor from one google sheets file on another/

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have two google sheet files:
1 - Manager
2 - Employee

I want to change the permissions for an employee on the Employee file, using a cell value on the Manager file.

So that the manager could enter his sheet, enter a "1" or a "0" in a specific cell, and toggle the employee permission on the Employee file on or off.

Comment: Accept tags edit, then right users can see and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect the sheet so the user can't make changes to it or you can hide the sheet but if the manager unhides the sheet the user can see it.

This two options are described on [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656) but they should not be used as a security method.

As a security method you can create two different spreadsheets and give access to the specific users you want.

You can have all the data on the Manager spreadsheet and then by using [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340) you can select what the Employee sees.